# What are good unit tests to cover the use case of rolling a die?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I'm trying to get to grips with unit testing.

Say we have a die which can has a default number of sides equal to 6 (but can be 4, 5 sided etc.):

```
import random
class Die():
    def __init__(self, sides=6):
        self._sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self._sides)
```

Would the following be valid/useful unit tests?

- test a roll in the range 1-6 for a 6 sided die
- test a roll of 0 for a 6 sided die
- test a roll of 7 for a 6 sided die
- test a roll in the range 1-3 for a 3 sided die
- test a roll of 0 for a 3 sided die
- test a roll of 4 for a 3 sided die

I'm just thinking that these are a waste of time as the random module has been around for long enough but then i think if the random module gets updated (say i update my Python version) then at least i'm covered.

Also, do I even need to test other variations of die rolls e.g. the 3 in this case, or is it good to cover another initialized die state?

Comment: What about a minus-5-sided die, or a null-sided die?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are right, your tests should not verify that the `random` module is doing its job; a unittest should only test the class itself, not how it interacts with other code (which should be tested separately).

It is of course entirely possible that your code uses `random.randint()` wrong; or you be calling `random.randrange(1, self._sides)` instead and your die never throws the highest value, but that'd be a different kind of bug, not one you could catch with a unittest. In that case, your `die` *unit* is working as designed, but the design itself was flawed.

In this case, I'd use mocking to *replace* the `randint()` function, and only verify that it has been *called* correctly. Python 3.3 and up comes with the [`unittest.mock` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock) to handle this type of testing, but you can install the external [`mock` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) on older versions to get the exact same functionality

```
import unittest
try:
    from unittest.mock import patch
except ImportError:
    # < python 3.3
    from mock import patch


@patch('random.randint', return_value=3)
class TestDice(unittest.TestCase):
    def _make_one(self, *args, **kw):
        from die import Die
        return Die(*args, **kw)

    def test_standard_size(self, mocked_randint):
        die = self._make_one()
        result = die.roll()

        mocked_randint.assert_called_with(1, 6)
        self.assertEqual(result, 3)

    def test_custom_size(self, mocked_randint):
        die = self._make_one(sides=42)
        result = die.roll()

        mocked_randint.assert_called_with(1, 42)
        self.assertEqual(result, 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

With mocking, your test is now very simple; there are only 2 cases, really. The default case for a 6-sided die, and the custom sides case.

There are other ways to temporarily replace the `randint()` function in the global namespace of `Die`, but the `mock` module makes this easiest. The [`@mock.patch` decorator](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#mock.patch) here applies to *all* test methods in the test case; each test method is passed an extra argument, the mocked `random.randint()` function, so we can test against the mock to see if it it indeed has been called correctly. The `return_value` argument specifies what is returned from the mock when it is called, so we can verify that the `die.roll()` method indeed returned the 'random' result to us.

I've used another Python unittesting best practice here: import the class under test as part of the test. The `_make_one` method does the importing and instantiation work *within a test*, so that the test *module* will still load even if you made a syntax error or other mistake that'll prevent the original module to import.

This way, if you made a mistake in the module code itself, the tests will still be run; they'll just fail, telling you about the error in your code.

To be clear, the above tests are simplistic in the extreme. The goal here is not to test that `random.randint()` has been called with the right arguments, for example. Instead, the goal is to test that the unit is producing the right results given certain inputs, where those inputs include the results of other units *not* under test. By mocking the `random.randint()` method you get to take control over just another input to your code.

In *real world* tests, the actual code in your unit-under-test is going to be more complex; the relationship with inputs passed to the API and how other units are then invoked can be interesting still, and mocking will give you access to intermediate results, as well as let you set the return values for those calls.

For example, in code that authenticates users against a 3rd party OAuth2 service (a multi-stage interaction), you want to test that your code is passing the right data to that 3rd party service, and lets you mock out different error responses that that 3rd party service would return, letting you simulate different scenarios without having to build a full OAuth2 server yourself. Here it is important to test that information from a first response have been handled correctly and have been passed on to a second stage call, so you do want to see that the mocked service is being called correctly.

Comment: You've got quite a few more than 2 test cases...
results check for default value: lower (1), upper (6), below lower (0), beyond upper (7)
and results for user specified numbers like max_int etc.
input also isn't validated, which may need to be tested for at some point...

Comment: No, those are tests for `randint()`, not the code in `Die.roll()`.

Comment: There's actually a way to ensure that not just randint is called correctly but that its result is used correctly too: mock it to return a `sentinel.die` for example (sentinel object is from `unittest.mock` too) and then verify that it is what was returned from your roll method. This actually allows only one way of implementing the tested method.

Comment: @aragaer: sure, if you want to verify that the value is returned unchanged, `sentinel.die` would be a great way to ensure that.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to ensure that mocked_randint is called_with certain values. I understand wanting to mock randint to return predictable values, but isn't the concern just that it returns predictable values and not what values it is called with?  It seems to me that checking the called values is unnecessarily tying the test to fine details of implementation. Also why do we care that the die returns the exact value of randint? Don't we really just care that it returns a value > 1 and less than equal to the max?

Comment: @bdrx: this is a very contrived example; but in many circumstances you do care about what arguments were passed to the `randint()` function. Perhaps you provide a simplified API to handle database connections, and you need to test that the inputs are correctly transformed to how the database connector is then called.

Answer (score 17):

[Martijn's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/225524/116461) is how you'd do it if you really wanted to run a test that demonstrates that you're calling random.randint. However, at the risk of being told "that doesn't answer the question", I feel this shouldn't be unit tested at all. Mocking randint is no longer black box testing - you're specifically showing that certain things are going on in the *implementation*. Black box testing it isn't even an option - there is no test you can execute that will prove that the result will *never* be less than 1 or more than 6.

Can you mock `randint`? Yes, you can. But what are you proving? That you called it with arguments 1 and sides. What does *that* mean? You're back in square one - at the end of the day you'll end up having to prove - [formally](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229592/in-functional-programming-how-does-one-achieve-modularity-through-mathematical-l/229605#229605) or informally - that calling `random.randint(1, sides)` correctly implements a dice roll.

I'm all for unit testing. They're fantastic sanity checks and expose the presence of bugs. However, they can never prove their absence, and there's things that can't be asserted through testing at all (e.g. that a particular function never throws an exception or always terminates.) In this particular case, I feel there's very little you stand to gain. For behavior that's deterministic, unit tests make sense because you actually know what the answer you're expecting will be.

Comment: Unit tests are not black box tests, really. That's what integration tests are for, to see to it that the various parts interact as designed. It's a matter of opinion, of course (most testing philosophy is), see [Does "Unit Testing" falls under white box or black box testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9892963) and [Black Box Unit Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10570915) for some (Stack Overflow) perspectives.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree that "that's what integration tests are for". Integration tests are for checking that all the components of the system interact correctly. They're not the place to test that a given component gives the correct output for a given input. As for black box vs white box unit testing, white box unit tests will eventually break with implementation changes, and any assumptions you've made in the implementation will likely carry over into the test. Validating that `random.randint` is called with `1, sides` is worthless if that's the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Yes, that's a limitation of a white-box unit test. However, there is *no point* in testing that `random.randint()` will correctly return values in the range [1, sides] (inclusive), that's up to the Python developers to ensure that the `random` unit works correctly.

Comment: And as you say yourself, unit testing cannot guarantee that your code is bug free; if your code is using other units wrongly (say, you expected `random.randint()` to behave like `random.randrange()` and thus call it with `random.randint(1, sides + 1)`, then you are sunk anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree with you there, but that's not what I'm objecting to. I'm objecting to *testing that random.randint is being called with arguments (1, sides)*. You have assumed in the implementation that this is the correct thing to do, and now you are repeating that assumption in the test. Should that assumption be wrong, the test will have passed but your implementation is still incorrect. It's a half-assed proof that's a full pain-in-the-ass to write and maintain.

Comment: @Doval: The demo unittest is simplistic in the extreme. Nothing happens with the return value of `random.randint()`. In real code the arguments passed to `random.randint()` would not have such a direct correlation with the class attributes, nor would the return value from the method calls simply be a pass-through. In other words, the point of a test would not be to assert that we called `random.randint()` with those arguments, but rather that the rest of the code handled inputs correctly, and produced the correct output.

Comment: @Doval:  Testing that other units have been invoked properly merely gives you access to intermediate values that the test might be interested in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That makes a lot more sense, but in that case you could just decouple the RNG and pass in a stub.

Comment: @Doval: That's what `mock` does, give you a clear and clean way of replacing external units with stubs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wouldn't call it "clear and clean" since you're essentially monkeypatching. The clean approach would be to use dependency injection. You could pass the RNG into a private constructor for testing purposes and have the public constructor default to `random.randint`. Alternatively, you could declare the `Die` class inside a function that takes the RNG as an argument, so you can do something like `RealDie = createDieClass(random.randint); TestDie = createDieClass(stubfunction); realD6 = RealDie(6); testD6 = TestDie(6)`.

Comment: Monkey-patching is the Python way; there is no such thing as a 'private constructor' in Python anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Fair point, I forgot that Python's syntax would not allow such a thing.

Answer (score 6):

Fix random seed. For 1, 2, 5 and 12-sided dice, confirm that a few thousand rolls gives results including 1 and N, and not including 0 or N + 1. If by seem freak chance you get a set of random results that don't cover the expected range, switch to a different seed.

Mocking tools are cool, but just because they allow you to do a thing doesn't mean that thing should be done. YAGNI applies to test fixtures as much as features.

If you can easily test with unmocked dependencies, you pretty much always should; that way your tests will be focused on reducing defect counts, not just increasing test count. Excess mocking risks creating misleading coverage figures, which in turn can lead to postponing the actual testing to some later phase you perhaps never have time to get round to...

Answer (score 3):

What is a `Die` if you think about it ? - no more than a wrapper around `random`. It encapsulates `random.randint` and relabels it in terms of your application's own vocabulary : `Die.Roll`.

I don't find it relevant to insert another layer of abstraction between `Die` and `random` because **`Die` itself is already this layer of indirection** between your application and the platform.

If you want canned dice results, *just mock `Die`, don't mock `random`*.

In general, I don't unit test my wrapper objects that communicate with external systems, I write integration tests for them. You could write a couple of those for `Die` but as you pointed out, due to the random nature of the underlying object, they will not be meaningful. In addition, there's no configuration or network communication involved here so not much to test except a platform call.

=> Considering that `Die` is only a few trivial lines of code and adds little to no logic compared to `random` itself, I'd skip testing it in that specific example.

Answer (score 2):

Seeding the random number generator and verifying expected results is NOT, as far as I can see, a valid test. It makes assumptions as to HOW your dice works internally, which is naughty-naughty. The developers of python could change the random number generator, or the die (NOTE: "dice" is plural, "die" is singular. Unless your class implements multiple die rolls in one call, it should probably be called "die") could use a different random number generator.

Similarly, mocking the random function assumes that the class implementation works exactly as expected. Why might this not be the case? Someone might take control of the default python random number generator, and to avoid that, a future version of your die may fetch several random numbers, or larger random numbers, to mix in more random data. A similar scheme was used by the makers of the FreeBSD operating system, when they suspected the NSA was tampering with the hardware random number generators built into CPUs.

If it were me, I'd run, say, 6000 rolls, tally them, and make sure that each number from 1-6 is rolled between 500 and 1500 times. I would also check that no numbers outside that range are returned. I might also check that, for a second set of 6000 rolls, when ordering the [1..6] in order of frequency, the result is different (this will fail once out of 720 runs, if the numbers are random!). If you want to be thorough, you might find the frequency of numbers following a 1, following a 2, etc; but make sure your sample size is big enough, and you have enough variance. Humans expect random numbers to have fewer patterns than they actually do.

Repeat for a 12 sided, and 2 sided die (6 is the most used, so is the most expected for anyone writing this code).

Finally, I would test to see what happens with a 1-sided die, a 0 sided die, a -1 sided die, a 2.3 sided die, a [1,2,3,4,5,6] sided die, and a "blah"-sided die. Of course, these should all fail; do they fail in a useful way? These should probably fail on creation, not on rolling.

Or, perhaps, you want too handle these differently - perhaps creating a die with [1,2,3,4,5,6] should be acceptable - and perhaps "blah" as well; this might be a die with 4 faces, and each face having a letter on it. The game "Boggle" springs to mind, as does a magic eight ball.

And finally, you might want to contemplate this: http://lh6.ggpht.com/-fAGXwbJbYRM/UJA_31ACOLI/AAAAAAAAAPg/2FxOWzo96KE/s1600-h/random%25255B3%25255D.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The tests you suggest in your question don't detect a modular arithmetic counter as implementation. And they don't detect common implementation errors in probability distribution related code like `return 1 + (random.randint(1,maxint) % sides)`. Or a change to the generator that results in 2-dimensional patterns.

If you actually want to verify that you are generating evenly distributed random-appearing numbers you need to check a very wide variety of properties. To do a reasonably good job at that you could run http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php on your generated numbers. Or write a similarly complex unit-test suite.

That's not the fault of unit-testing or TDD, randomness just happens to be a very difficult property to verify. And a popular topic for examples.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of swimming against the tide, I solved this exact problem a number of years ago using a method not so far mentioned.

My strategy was simply to mock the RNG with one that produces a predictable stream of values spanning the entire space. If (say) side=6 and the RNG produces values from 0 to 5 in sequence I can predict how my class should behave and unit test accordingly.

The rationale is that this tests the logic in this class alone, on the assumption that the RNG will eventually produce each of those values and without testing the RNG itself.

It's simple, deterministic, reproducible and it does catch bugs. I would use the same strategy again.

---

The question does not spell out what the tests should be, just what data might be used for testing, given the presence of an RNG. My suggestion is merely to test exhaustively by mocking the RNG. The question of what is worth testing depends on information not provided in the question.

Comment: Say you mock the RNG to be predictable. Well what do you then test? The question asks "Would the following be valid/useful unit tests?" Mocking it to return 0-5 is not a test but rather test setup. How would you "unit test accordingly"? I am failing to understand how it "does catch bugs". I am having a hard time understanding what I need to 'unit' test.

Comment: @bdrx: This was a while ago: I would answer it differently now. But see edit.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest test of a die-roll is simply to repeat it several hundred-thousand times, and validate that each possible result was hit roughly (1 / number of sides) times.  In the case of a 6-sided die, you should see each possible value hit about 16.6% of the time.  If any are off by more than a percent, then you have a problem.

Doing it this way avoids allows you to refactor the underlying mechanic of generating a random number easily, and most importantly, without changing the test.

Comment: this test would pass for a totally non-random implementation that simply loops through sides one by one in a predefined order

Comment: If a coder is intent on implementing something in bad faith (not using a randomizing agent on a die), and simply trying to find something to 'make the red lights turn green' you have more problems than unit testing can really solve.